# Flutter/Dart force request to use wifi, even with no internet

Tags: android, flutter, dart, wifi

My flutter app on Android 10 (APK 29) is connected to wifi device with no internet using  `flutter_wifi_connect` plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wifi_connect). The plugin uses Android WifiNetworkSpecifier API. I am also connected to cellular network at the same time.

I'm sending requests to the local network device (with IP address in URL), but it fails randomly.

I suspect Android tries cellular network instead of wifi sometimes.

Firing the request

```
final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('http://192.168.174.117:8080/api/test'),
);
```

gives me following error, but only sometimes. Sometimes it works.

```
I/flutter (27829): SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 192.168.174.117, port = 38166
```

If I turn off mobile data manually, it works every time.

I tried another plugin `wifi_iot` (https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot) and add this before the request

```
await WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(true);
```

but with no luck.

I updated flutter to 2.1.0.-11.0.pre.122, didn't help.

User has an option to resend the request so eventually it works, but it's terrible user experience, I must not let it like this.

Is there any way how to force using wifi for a specific request (or force NOT to use cellular network for a specific request)? App works in a way it communicates with wifi device that provides wifi, but also needs to be connected to internet with cellular network.

Answer (score 1):

The packages *wifi_iot* and *http* are working for me. Had also the problem that only if mobile data was switched off via android UI a http call could be done.

I found that after connecting with `WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect()` it's needed to call `WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(true)` - then do your HTTP calls even if mobile data is activated.

To keep everything ok you may call
before disconnect:

```
WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(false);
```

then disconnect

connect again to another Wifi or default

```
WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(true);
```